# I want to return an XML response I already have using Go

Tags: xml, go, mocking

I want to print out an XML response for which I already have done something like below (refer code block).

Instead of `hello`; print out the whole response anyone knows how I could do that?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
 http.HandleFunc("/hello", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
      w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/xml")

  fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello\n")
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. do you want `hello` be in a XML or you have a response like an struct value that you want to convert it to XML and print it out.

Comment: @shakingbaking Mark it as accepted if you're satisfied with the answer.

Comment: if i hit localhost:8080/hello 
 
return 
`<soap:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://sample.com/schema/sample/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns3:helloResponse>
            <ns2:correlationId>STR12345</ns2:correlationId>
            <ns2:status>
                <ns2:statusCode>0</ns2:statusCode>
                <ns2:statusMessage>Success</ns2:statusMessage>
            </ns2:status>
          
        </ns3:helloResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
`

Answer (score 3):

I think you expect something like this, right?

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "net/http"
)

// Response XML struct
type Response struct {
    Greeting string
    Names    []string `xml:"Names>Name"`
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    response := Response{"Hello", []string{"World", "Sarkar"}}

    // Wraps the response to Response struct
    x, err := xml.MarshalIndent(response, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/xml")
    // Write
    w.Write(x)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
}
```

Output:

```xml
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2020 07:01:46 GMT
Content-Length: 119

<Response>
  <Greeting>Hello</Greeting>
  <Names>
    <Name>World</Name>
    <Name>Sarkar</Name>
  </Names>
</Response>
```

Comment: While this answers the question, it could still be improved by adding some basic error handling.

Comment: Would there be a way to just have a function return any xml response if i hit localhost:8090/variable just return the response if I already have it ?
 
like if I hit localhost:8090/hello

return 

<Response>
  <Greeting>Hello</Greeting>
  <Names>
    <Name>World</Name>
    <Name>Sarkar</Name>
  </Names>
</Response>

Comment: @shmsr I want to be able to provide the response as a string so it can simply return it whenever it hits the url for example if u go to localhost:8090/hello return the whole `<Response> <Greeting>Hello</Greeting> <Names> <Name>World</Name> <Name>Sarkar</Name> </Names> </Response>` but if i want to manipulate what it returns just update the string and it'll return the same

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to build an XML document like

```xml
<Greeting><text>hello</text></Greeting>
```

This can be done using the [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Encoder) package.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

// Greeting is the struct for an XML greeting.
type Greeting struct {
    Text string `xml:"text"`
}

func main() {
    // Create a new greeting.
    g := &Greeting{Text: "hello"}

    // Encode it into a bytes buffer.
    var b bytes.Buffer
    enc := xml.NewEncoder(&b)
    if err := enc.Encode(g); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // This will print <Greeting><text>hello</text></Greeting>
    fmt.Println(b.String())
}
```